# Installer Workflow Manager SharePoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, workflow, sharepoint-server, workflow-manager

I cannot finish installing Workflow Manager SharePoint 2013. My environment is Windows Server 2012 R2, SharePoint Enterprise.

I follow the steps according to this article [SharePoint 2013 workflow installing](http://blog.fpweb.net/sharepoint-2013-workflow-installing-and-configuring/) But everytime it has a permission error.

I use the account which is **administrator** on the computer and it has **SysAdmin** privilege on this SQL Server instance. It has right of **dbcreator**. I don't understand why I don't have permission. How can I know which permission I need ?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The user that is configuring Workflow Manager must meet following requirements.
If the machine is domain joined, the user must be a domain user; otherwise the user must be a local user.

The user must be an administrator on the computer on which the configuration is running.

The user must have **SysAdmin privilege on this SQL Server instance**, otherwise, the databases should be pre-created and the Sql logon for the RunAs Account User should be created manually, before running the configuration, on all Sql instances.

**More information:**

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj193451.aspx

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/briangre/archive/2013/02/20/least-privilege-configuration-for-windows-azure-workflow-with-sharepoint-2013.aspx

Comment: Thank you for information, but I don't understand why databases should be pre-created ? It is not created during the Workflow Configuration Wizard ? I am not good at SQL.